# How to close current tkinter window and open a new tkinter window when the user inputs test into a tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to close the current tkinter window, and open a new tkinter window when the user inputs text into an entry widget. That might sound confusing so let me explain.

> First tkinter window:

[image: First window]

When the user inputs text into the Entry widget, I would like this current window to close and the second window to open with the text the user entered displayed in a label widget.

> Second window:

[image: Window 2]

> Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
user_input = ''

class Startup_window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        master.title('Window 1')

        def get_input(event):
            global user_input
            # Gets the user input from the Entry widget
            user_input = self.input.get()
            # Clears Entry widget
            self.input.delete(0, END)
            master.destroy()

        self.label = Label(master, text='Input:')
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.input = Entry(master)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.input.focus()

        self.input.bind("<Return>", get_input)


class Main_window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        master.title('Window 2')

        self.label = Label(master, text="You've entered (user_input)" + user_input)
        self.label.pack()

root = Tk()

startup_window = Startup_window(root)
if user_input != '':
    main_window = Main_window(root)

mainloop()
```

I am new to tkinter and object oriented programming so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe its not good to say `global` with OOP and for this effect i think you could `bind` the `<Return>` key to make the window close

Comment: Also noticed that `if user_input != '':` gets run when you first run your code, that is initially your entry widget is empty and hence it wont get executed. also keep in mind, both works in the same `root = Tk()` which means your overwriting one GUI window and not creating a new window so maybe use `Toplevel()` somewhere

Comment: @CoolCloud Doesnt that portion of code loop due to the `mainloop()` at the bottom?

Comment: yes but the code checks the condition once, ONLY, after that they dont, that is why we usually put `.get()` inside of a function to be invoked later. `mainloop()` doesnt mean we are repeating the blocks of code right in between in, i guesss

Comment: @CoolCloud I understand. Is there any way to achieve the goal I proposed in the question?

Comment: Im not experienced with OOP, you might wanna wait for some more opinions

Comment: @Neo630 Are you looking for something like triggering a button on entry field to get the value and throw it in other window? or pressing enter key like that?

Comment: @CoolCloud OK, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Karthik pressing the enter key in the entry widget, which I have working, the part that isn't working is closing the current window and opening another one with the inputted text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for you. As @CoolCloud mentioned, the `if` condition will be checked only once. Because `mainloop()` actually waits for events to be triggered (maybe through some `buttons` or whatever), ***NOT*** that it executes the blocks of code over and over again

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApp():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.inputBox = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.inputBox.pack()
        self.inputBox.bind('<Return>', self.checkInput)

    def checkInput(self, args):
        if self.inputBox.get() != '':
            userVal = self.inputBox.get()
            self.root.destroy() # try root.quit if it doesn't work
            newWindow = tk.Tk()
            myLabel = tk.Label(newWindow, text='You entered: ' + userVal)
            myLabel.pack()

win = tk.Tk()
MainApp(win)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a clever way of doing it.